# Visual c++ libraries

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2017, installation, redistributable

I'm currently working in VS2017 on a solution with multiple C# and C++ projects. 
The installer project has the C++ redistributable as a prerequisite, with the option to download it from the component vendor's site.

Some of the clients want to be able to install the application without an internet connection.

The normal thing would be to put the package in the bootstraper and check the download from the same location as my application; the problem is every time Microsoft updates something with this library, compiling the application would work, but installation will have the old redistributable.

Is there any check to include Visual Studio libraries that are used when building the application, which ever version these may be?

Comment: *but the problem is every time microsoft updates something with this libraries* -- The issue of having to use newer versions of the VC runtime libraries is no longer an issue starting with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Visual studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 have the same redistributable https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads What is exactly your problem in this case ?

Comment: So if i add now the vcredist_x86 in the project as prerequisite (having the vcredist_x86.exe - 14.0.23026 in bootstrapper) when/if microsoft will make another one, lets say 14.0.35xxx, and my c++ project will compile/build with the new one, i will have no problem installing the application with the old version thats in bootstrapper? because thats what im looking for, a solution to not check every time what microsoft updated when i build the solution and send it to customer. i hope this makes some sense